# Retrieve remote xml file in net-core console app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm porting a small .net app to a .net-core console project. In my old project I have:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\path\file.xml")
IEnumerable<Car> cars = from car in xml.Root.Descendants("car")
select new Car
{
    CarId = car.Element("Car_ID")?.Value,
    Make = car.Element("Car_Make")?.Value,
    Model = car.Element("Car_Model")?.Value
}
// do something with cars list
```

Works fine in .net-core as well, however in my .net-core project we need to work with remote xml files. If I use a Url instead of a local file path, like so:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"https://website/file.xml")
```

... then I get an error:

```
The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path
```

I've found lots of samples using XmlDocument and file-streams, but they either don't compile in .net-core, or aren't complete enough to help me out.

What is required to make this work?

*edited to add more detail

Comment: I think it's not implemented on Core, download the file as a string with a WebClient and feed it to the XDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using HTTPClient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Comment: @JohnL Glad to hear it! Please mark as answered? :D